# Universal SQL query for different input elements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query problem with the following abstract sample context: There are 2 different input data for my sql query defined as ''MainElement'' with key 123 for the one and 789 for the other main element.

Further I have a table called **Relation** with columns `pk`, `FirstElement`, `SecondElement` and `ThirdElement`.

Furthermore there is a table called **Props** with the columns `pk`, `name` and `valueString`. The special feature about this context is that column `name` in **Props** defines 2 further columns called `4thElement` and `5thElement`of table **Relation** as a row with its values in column `valueString` .

```
|pk | 1stElement | 2ndElement | 3rdElement |
|abc|-----123----|-----456----|-----null---|
|def|-----789----|-----101112-|---131415---|

|Pk | Name | ValueString |
|def|4thElement|161718---|
|def|5thElement|ghi------|
```

As you can see the `MainElement` **789** has a value for `4thElement` and `5thElement` in **Props**, but `MainElement` **123** hasn't any value in **Props**.

What I need is an universal SQL query with input value `1stElement` e.g., 123 or 789 that returns me a result for both main elements independent of the fact that `MainElement` 123 hasn't any value in **Props**.

Sample result:

```
|1stElement | 2ndElement | 3rdElement | 4thElement | 5thElement |
|123--------|------456---|-----null---|---null-----|----null----|
|789--------|----101112--|---131415---|---161718---|----ghi-----|
```

I am using **Oracle SQL Developer**.

```
Select 
rel.1stElement,
....
From 
Relation rel,
Props pro,
Where 
?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say that input value will be "*123 **or** 789*", but then want to have "*result for **both** main elements*". Isn't it a self-contradictory? Please clarify.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be self-contradictory? I want to use this sql query in general for both inputs. First sql query with input 123 and secondly with 789 or vice versa. Not both simultaneously for an execution. The problem is that I get an empty result when I have input 123 because in table Props I haven't any entry with pk abc ;-)))

Comment: You query outline hints at `INNER JOIN` that eliminates any `NULL`  values.  `OUTER JOIN` should take care of it. It's not clear if you can have **multiple** values of `4thElement` and `5thElement` for the same `pk`.  In either way, it seems that the already suggested answer would do the job.  If it does not, you will need to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work, this is typically a pivot query that you need:

```
SELECT rel.pk, rel.1stElement, rel.2ndElement, rel.3rdElement 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN pro.Name = '4thElement' 
           THEN pro.ValueString 
           ELSE NULL
           END) as 4thElement
     , MAX(CASE WHEN pro.Name = '5thElement' 
           THEN pro.ValueString
           ELSE NULL
           END) as 5thElement
FROM Relation rel 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Props pro 
        ON rel.pk = pro.pk
GROUP BY rel.pk, rel.1stElement, rel.2ndElement, rel.3rdElement
```